# Three.JS - AudioAnalyser() not working with audio source as Stream type in Safari

Tags: three.js, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, audio-analysis

I'm developing a streaming radio in 3D using **Three.JS**, I'm sending music as a PeerConnection to my clients attaching a `THREE.AudioAnalyser()` to display 3D bars that move according to frequencies.

Sound is working great in all platforms, but `THREE.AudioAnalyser()` with an input source of stream type only works on Chrome, Safari is not working at all :frowning:

```
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
var audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );
audio.setMediaStreamSource( stream );
audioAnalyser = new THREE.AudioAnalyser( audio, 128 );

function loop(){
    console.log(audioAnalyser.getFrequencyData());
}
```

The `console.log()` of the `loop()` function should contain an Array of Integers, on Chrome is all good, Safari logs `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

What could be causing this issue? It seems to work everywhere but not on Safari, and also it only seems to fail when the source is a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you might want to connect the output of the `AnalyserNode` to the destination node.  You may want to stick a `GainNode` with a gain of 0 in between, just in case you don't really want the audio from the `AnalyserNode` to be played out.